# SQL Server trigger - Insert into new table when old table has an update/insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update, insert-update

I'm trying to create a sort of tracking trigger that will insert all changes / new entries from one table into a new table. The point of this is to see who was the last user to modify a record.

This is the code I used:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SV00300_Tracking ON sv00300
FOR INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO [GP_Tracking].[dbo].[SV00300] (Col1, col2, col3)
        SELECT Col1, col2, col3
        FROM inserted
go
```

Comment: OK.  What database?  What have you tried?  Did you get an error?  What error?

Comment: SQL Server.  I have tried an Insert Trigger, but I think I am going too simple here. I didn't receive an error, but I am not producing the results I want. Basically I just want to see all changes done to a table but to put those records into a separate table.

Comment: Is `[GP_Tracking].[dbo].[SV00300]` a different table than `sv00300`?  They have the same name.  But maybe you're trying to move the data into a table in a different database?  What is the `insert` statement you run to insert the row into the table on which the trigger is defined?  What, exactly, happens when you run that `insert` statement?  You say you aren't getting the results you want but you're not telling us what results you expect.

Comment: GP_Tracking.DBO.sv00300 is a table in a different database. The result right now is absolutely nothing, and the result I expect is "I just want to see all changes done to a table but to put those records into a separate table" I want to see ALL modifications done to the original sv00300 table. Perhaps I should go about this a different way?

Comment: Is the table on teh same server?

Comment: Yep. We are running Dynamics GP and there are a lot of users that can go in an change records, and I want to be able to know who changed what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER SV00300_Tracking ON sv00300
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

INSERT INTO [GP_Tracking].[dbo].[SV00300]
        (Col1, col2, col3
      )
    SELECT
        Col1, col2, col3
        FROM inserted

go
```

That should do it!

Comment: Mind blown! That was a little too simple.

Comment: You also should consider using a synonym instead of a hard-coded database.schema.table inside the trigger.